# Add a header to wkhtmltoimage

Tags: cmd, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I am trying to add some text the top of an html image using wkhtmltoimage. I am not sure if I am using the right argument. At the moment, I am failing with...

`wkhtmltoimage --custom-header helloworld http://www.google.com google.png`

The [help file](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) suggests I need a value after the text. It is not clear to me what this represents. I also would like to add more than one word (e.g. `hello world`). Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--custom-header` is for sending [HTTP request headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) to a URL, not for making headers as you would in a word processor.

For example, if you have a multilingual website that responds to the `Accept-Language` request header, you can request a specific language version by sending the custom header:

```
wkhtmltopdf --custom-header Accept-Language fr-CA http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

In this example, `--custom-header` is used to request the Canadian-French (`fr-CA`) version of Google.

What you're probably looking for is the `--header-html` option, which is available with `wkhtmltopdf` (but not with `wkhtmltoimage`, from what I can tell):

```
wkhtmltopdf --header-html /path/to/your/header/file.html http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

In this example, whatever HTML code is found in `/path/to/your/header/file.html` file gets prepended as the header.

Read more about all of the [header/footer options](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html) in the manual.

Comment: adding User-Agent option in custom header in wkhtmltopdf  is not working. it is giving default site view only.

Comment: I got the solution for executing useragent in wkhtmltopdf, use --custom-header-propagation in command.